# Not getting proper output after clicking on Switch Name button in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Not getting proper output after clicking on Switch Name button in ReactJs

App.js:

```js
        state = {
            persons: [
              { name: 'Max', age: 25 },
              { name: 'Manu', age: 29 },
              { name: 'Stephanie', age: 26 }
            ]
        }

        switchNameHandler = () => {
            console.log('Was clicked!');      
        }

        render() {
            return (
              <div className="App">
                <h1> Working................ </h1>
                <Person name={this.state.persons[0].name} age={this.state.persons[0].age} />
                <Person name="abc" age="20" />
                <Person name="uvw" age="20" />
                <Person name="uvw" age="20" />
                <Person name="lmno" age="20" >Working.........</Person>
                <button onClick={this.switchNameHandler()}>switch Name</button>
              </div>
            );
        }
```

Output: (after clicking 6-7 times)

```
log.js:24 [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
react-dom.development.js:24994 Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: .....
App.js:20 Was clicked!
App.js:20 Was clicked!
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.postload.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
Grammarly.js:2 [DEFAULT]: WARN : Using DEFAULT root logger
```

Comment: change `this.switchNameHandler()` to `() => this.switchNameHandler()`

Comment: @StackedQ It is working but can you please explain to me why this.switchNameHandler() is not working for me but it is working for instructor whose tutorials I'm following

Comment: Because that will fire the function on render, but `() => this.switchNameHandler()` means run this function onclick, first one is a function call, but the latter is a function callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is here.

```
<button onClick={this.switchNameHandler()}>switch Name</button>
```

You dont need the `()` at the end of function. If you have `()` the `switchNameHandler` function is *executed* and the return value (if any) of the function is assigned to the onClick handler.

You need to give onClick like this

```
<button onClick={this.switchNameHandler}>switch Name</button>
```

or

```
<button onClick={()=>this.switchNameHandler()}>switch Name</button>
```

onClick expects a function, not the return of a function unless the return is another function.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make the function a variable, same with your object. Try this:

```
var state = {
    persons: [
      { name: 'Max', age: 25 },
      { name: 'Manu', age: 29 },
      { name: 'Stephanie', age: 26 }
    ]
  }
var switchNameHandler = () => {
  console.log('Was clicked!');
  
}
```